# Using the prawn-qrcode gem to render a QR code in a PDF via prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdf-generation, qr-code, prawn

Newer to programming and this is my second question.  The prawn-qrcode looks like my solution but the installation instructions are a bit vague as to where the code should go.  Appreciate the help here and there may be a few mistakes in my code.

```
**Gem File**

gem 'devise'
gem 'linkedin'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin'
gem 'haml'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'rqrcode', "~> 0.4.2"
gem 'prawn-qrcode', "~> 0.2.0"
gem 'will_paginate', '> 3.0'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'prawn'
gem 'hirb'

Relevant section of the controller 

def show
@property = Property.find(params[:id])
@qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new(property_path, :size => 6, :level => :h )
@prospect = Prospect.new

respond_to do |format|
     format.html # show.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @property }
     format.pdf do
           pdf = PropertyPdf.new(@property)
           send_data pdf.render, type: "application/pdf",
                                 disposition: "inline"
     end
end
end

Prawn PDF View

class PropertyPdf < Prawn::Document

def initialize(property)
    super(top_margin: 70)
    @property = property
    @qrcode_content = 'http://tbd.com'
    qrcode
    building_heading

end

def qrcode
 print_qr_code(@qrcode_content, :dot=>2.8)
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome (quite belatedly) to the world of programming.  :)  In case you're still around, just a note that this question would benefit from paring it down to as simple a test case as you can muster -- for example, we probably don't need to know about the linkedin and omniauth stuff (among others), and it would be helpful to separate out questions about _generating_ PDFs with QR codes (which is what I think this question is about) versus _sending_ generated PDFs in some sort of web response.   It's fine, just giving what I hope is constructive feedback for the future. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is:

```
require 'prawn/qrcode'
```

It automatically registers as an extension with Prawn and you can use in your PDF generation.

The examples in the github project also should cover most use cases:

https://github.com/jabbrwcky/prawn-qrcode/tree/master/examples

Cheers,
Jens

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to work. If I put it in the PDF file in the def qrcode area nothing changes. If I put it anywhere else I get the follow error: LoadError in PropertiesController#show no such file to load -- prawn/qrcode

Comment: I understand that the code you posted are just fragments - a more complete example would aid in finding a solution. The snippet looks like the generated qrcode is assigned to a local variable in `initialize()` which is then referenced in `qrcode` where it can only be undefined because it is out of scope.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to tell me above

Comment: @sjustinbrown Here is a gist that should work: https://gist.github.com/jabbrwcky/5830562

Comment: These lines in your initialize method:
    `qrcode_content = 'http://tbd.com'`
    `qrcode = RQRCode::QRCode.new('http://tbd.com', :size => 6, :level => :h )`

assign values to variables in the local scope of the method, so `qrcode_content` and `qrcode`will be undefined anywhere else unless there is some code missing in your snippet.

So assuming the code in your snippet is complete,`qrcode_content` will always be undefined/empty in the call `print_qr_code(qrcode_content, :dot=>2.8)`

Comment: It worked.  Didn't really need qrcode = or qrcode_content =.  Just initialize qrcode and                                               def qrcode
     print_qr_code(@qrcode_content, :dot=>2.8)
end